# Android device not listed on 'lsusb' Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: usb, bluetooth

i hope you will help me in this known issue. I have Huawei P9 lite device what worked fine while whas connected with windows os and also on older Ubuntu versions what i used before.

It's connected right by bluetooth and can send files to each other and connect to internet using by bluetooth connection working fine too. But when i connect device to pc by usb, it's just changing device.

```
user@user:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b00a Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04ca:7092 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
user@user:~$ lsusb | grep Bluetooth

user@user:~$ mtp-detect
libmtp version: 1.1.13
Listing raw device(s)
   No raw devices found.
user@user:~$ sudo apt install mtp-tools
[sudo] heslo pro user: 
Načítají se seznamy balíků… Hotovo
Vytváří se strom závislostí       
Načítají se stavové informace… Hotovo
mtp-tools je již nejnovější verze (1.1.13-1).
0 aktualizováno, 0 nově instalováno, 0 k odstranění a 0 neaktualizováno.

user@user:~$ sudo apt-get install bluez-utils libopenobex1 bluez-tools 
Načítají se seznamy balíků… Hotovo
Vytváří se strom závislostí       
Načítají se stavové informace… Hotovo
Balík bluez-utils není dostupný, ale jiný balík se na něj odkazuje.
To může znamenat že balík chybí, byl zastarán, nebo je dostupný
pouze z jiného zdroje
Nicméně následující balíky jej nahrazují:
  bluez:i386 bluez

Balík libopenobex1 není dostupný, ale jiný balík se na něj odkazuje.
To může znamenat že balík chybí, byl zastarán, nebo je dostupný
pouze z jiného zdroje

E: Balík „bluez-utils“ nemá kandidáta pro instalaci
E: Balík „libopenobex1“ nemá kandidáta pro instalaci
user@user:~$
```

Thank you in advance. 
Matej